# Windows Phone 8.1 App not deploying on device

Tags: windows, deployment, windows-phone-8.1, cordova-3

I have created an Mobile App for Windows Phone 8.1 using tools for Apache Cordova. When trying to Sideload the app using the windows phone 8.1 application deployment tool i receive an error "Error - A packaging error prevented this application from installing". Does anyone know what this means, the cause and how to fix it? The process is inconsistent as there are times it works without issues and other times it doesn't work constantly any ideas.